# C++17 codecvt throw "bad conversion" when convert std::string to std::wstring

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, visual-c++, c++17

I wrote a string class called `UString` and I want is can convert `std::string` to `std::wstring`,and also convert `std::wstring` to `std::string`.

I'm using the  libary in c++17,so I wrote code as follows.

In UString.h:

```cpp
public:
        UString(std::string s);                         
    UString(std::wstring ws);   
private:
    std::string str;                                
    std::string WTS(const std::wstring & wstr);
    std::wstring STW(const std::string & str);
public:
        std::wstring w_str();                           
    const wchar_t* wc_str();
```

In UString.cpp:

```cpp
UString::UString(std::string s)
{
    str = s;
}
UString::UString(std::wstring ws)
{
    str = WTS(ws);
}
std::string UString::WTS(const std::wstring & wstr)
{
    std::string ret;
    try {
        std::wstring_convert< std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> > wcv;
        ret = wcv.to_bytes(wstr);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return ret;
}
std::wstring UString::STW(const std::string & str)
{
    std::wstring ret;
    try {
        std::wstring_convert< std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> > wcv;
        ret = wcv.from_bytes(str);
    }
    catch (const std::exception & e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return ret;
}
std::wstring UString::w_str()
{
    return STW(str);
}
const wchar_t* UString::wc_str()
{
    return STW(str).c_str();
}
```

And it should work like that:

```cpp
UString ustr="test"; //the value should be "test"
UString ustr2=L"test2"; //the value should be "test2"
wcout<<ustr.w_str()<<endl; //the value should be "test"
cout<<ustr.wc_str()<<endl; //the value should be "test"
```

In linux,GCC 8.0.1,the class works fine,but in windows,Visual Studio 2017,when I use the `UString::w_str()` or `UString::wc_str()`,it  can not work and throw an "bad conversion" error.
What should I do to make this work?

Comment: Looks like you have UB in your code, returning a pointer to something on the stack

Comment: It's worth noting that in Windows, wchar_t represents a UTF16 character and in every other operating system it represents a 32-bit code point. Unfortunately this makes wchar_t completely incompatible between systems. I strongly suspect you'll need conditional code to cope with the windows case.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://rextester.com/JKJ68999).`w_str()` call works for me, and produces expected data. `std::cout << wc_str()` prints the address stored in the pointer, since you are outputting a `wchar_t*` into a narrow stream. If you were using `std::wcout` instead, the program would exhibit undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wc_str()` returns a dangling pointer; any use of its return value by the caller exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended.

`STW(str)` produces a temporary, then `c_str()` takes a pointer to data managed by that temporary. Then the temporary is destroyed, taking the data down with it, and the pointer becomes dangling.

Comment: Probably by not providing `wc_str()` member at all. `w_str()` should be sufficient.

Comment: But the ```w_str()``` function can't work too.It throws ```bad_conversion``` error.

Comment: As I mentioned in an earlier comment, [can't reproduce](https://rextester.com/JKJ68999)